# How to get the revision history of user from Rally using Node js scripting

Tags: javascript, node.js, rally

My requirement is to get the exact date/time when a user gets disabled.
To achieve this, I need to query for the line 'user set to INACTIVE' in the Revision History to find the date the user was switched from enabled to disabled.
How can I get the revision history using node js ? 
I tried below code, but its not working as Rally support team mentioned that its older code and i have to try with v2.0. 
Can somebody help me to achieve my requirement ?

```js
var revisions = story.RevisionHistory.Revisions;
revisions.sort(byRevisionNumber);

var story_was_blocked = false;
// it doesn't matter how many revs have been in BLOCKED state, presence of one is sufficient
for (var rix = 0; rix < revisions.length && story_was_blocked === false; rix++) {
  var rev = revisions[rix];
  if (rev.Description.indexOf("BLOCKED changed from ") >= 0) {
    story_was_blocked = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief example of how this might be accomplished. Note that this just shows how to fetch all revisions in the collection on a User, you'd need to iterate through them and match the Description field on 'Disabled':

```
var rally = require('rally'),
queryUtils = rally.util.query,
rallyApi = rally({
    // Example key, not valid
    apiKey: '_UkMasZfjPZfquDIMExfEKnAboQUlyT2SP4UppMHir',
    server: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com',
    requestOptions: {
        headers: {
            'X-RallyIntegrationName': 'Query User Revisions',
            'X-RallyIntegrationVendor': 'Stackoverflow user4211235',
            'X-RallyIntegrationVersion': '1.0'
        }
    }
});

function onError(error) {
    console.log('Failure!', error);
}

function queryUserRevisions(result) {
    var revisions = result.Revisions;
    rallyApi.query({
        ref: revisions,
        start: 1,
        limit: Infinity,
        order: 'RevisionNumber',
        fetch: ['RevisionNumber','Description','CreationDate']
    }, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            onError(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success querying User Revisions...');
            console.log('Summary of revisions on User:')
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

function queryUserRevisionHistory(result) {
    rallyApi.query({
        ref: result.Results[0].RevisionHistory,
        start: 1,
        limit: Infinity,
        fetch: ['Revisions','RevisionNumber','Description','CreationDate']
    }, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            onError(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success querying User Revision History. Querying Revisions...');
            queryUserRevisions(result);
        }
    });
}

function queryUser(callback) {
    rallyApi.query({
        type: 'user',
        start: 1,
        pageSize: 2,
        limit: 10,
        order: 'CreationDate',
        fetch: ['UserName', 'EmailAddress', 'RevisionHistory'],
        query: queryUtils.where('UserName', '=', "user@company.com")
    }, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            onError(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success querying User. Querying Revision History...');
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}

queryUser(queryUserRevisionHistory);
```

Comment: The code is working for me. But I have another question, I am creating an RestApi connection in another class called RallyDataLoader, so I am not able to use the same in this particular class. How can do that?

Comment: The code displays only the first user revision history. you have to always filter with the username ?

Comment: While the example queries for only one user, you can elect to poll the users collection to get multiple users if you wish.